# Attempted import error: 'create' is not exported from 'fontkit' (imported as 'fontkit')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I'm using the `react-pdf/renderer` package to add functionality to download a pdf from my website. But I'm getting this error message: `./node_modules/@react-pdf/font/lib/index.browser.es.js Attempted import error: 'create' is not exported from 'fontkit' (imported as 'fontkit').`

I tried to use different versions of this package, such as v2.2.0, v2.3.0 and v3.0.0, but unfortunately, nothing worked for me. I'm using `react v^17.0.2`.

PDF Document code:

```
import { Document, Page, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import React from "react";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "#E4E4E4",
  },
  section: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
});

const InvoicePDF = () => {
  return (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <Text>Section #1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <Text>Section #2</Text>
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};

export default InvoicePDF;
```

PDF Download button:

```
import React from "react";
import InvoicePDF from "../invoicePDF/InvoicePDF";
import { pdf } from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

const InvoiceFooter = ({ data }) => {
  return (
        <button
          className="w-full text-white text-sm font-bold px-6 py-4 rounded-full transition bg-borderOne hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-borderOne"
          onClick={async () => {
            const doc = <InvoicePDF />;
            const asPdf = pdf([]);
            asPdf.updateContainer(doc);
            const blob = await asPdf.toBlob();
            saveAs(blob, "document.pdf");
          }}
        >
          Download PDF
        </button>
  );
};

export default InvoiceFooter;
```

Comment: have you checked the library github repo issues? - https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1991

Comment: I checked, but there is no solution available.

Comment: The issue was reported 8 hours ago and the repo devs haven't found a solution yet - at least you know where to look now

Comment: I am also facing the issue while building on node version 14 but when I try with node 18 its working

Answer (score 15):

After doing a lot of research this one works for me.
Add:

```
"@react-pdf/renderer":" 2.1.0",
"@react-pdf/font": "2.2.0",
To your package.json dependencies.
```

Then below dependencies add:

```
"resolutions": {
    "@react-pdf/font": "2.2.0"
  },
```

If you already have a resolutions object you'll just need to add this version to it. Notice there is no ^ in the version number.

Then remove yarn.lock or package-lock.json and re-run yarn/npm install

Comment: Which version of react-pdf did you use?

Comment: I don't use @react-pdf only use above mention packages

Comment: There might be type: `"@react-pdf/renderer":" 2.1.0",`

Answer (score 9):

If you are using `npm` & not `yarn`, you could try the following

- Update `@react-pdf/renderer` from `^2.2.0` to `3.0.0`
- Add an `overrides` key to my `package.json` that looks like;

```json
"overrides": {
    "@react-pdf/font": "2.2.1",
    "@react-pdf/pdfkit": "2.1.0"
  }
```

Your `package.json` file should look something like;

```js
// other stuff in the package.json file
"dependencies": {
// other dependencies in the package.json file
   "@react-pdf/renderer": "3.0.0"
}
"overrides": {
    "@react-pdf/font": "2.2.1",
    "@react-pdf/pdfkit": "2.1.0"
}
// other stuff in the package.json file
```

Comment: This was the only solution here that worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
"@react-pdf/renderer": "2.1.0",
"@react-pdf/font": "2.2.0",

"resolutions": {
    "@react-pdf/font": "2.2.0"
  },
```

To your **package.json** dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I use yarn and this Github issue answer worked for me.

```
"resolutions": {
"@react-pdf/font": "2.2.1",
"@react-pdf/pdfkit": "2.1.0"
}
```

Link:
https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/2015#issuecomment-1246286312

As described in the issue thread "overrides" work for npm and resolutions work for yarn.

Answer (score 1):

Using yarn, I was able to solve the issue by adding:

```
"dependencies": {
// all other dependencies
"@react-pdf/renderer": "3.0.0",
}
```

Then:

```
"resolutions": {
"@react-pdf/font": "2.2.1",
"@react-pdf/pdfkit": "2.1.0"
},
```

As "resolutions" is to yarn like "overrides" is to npm.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `@react-pdf/renderer` in the scope of a `@microsoft/rush` based monorepository.

I am using `pnpm` to manage packages, therefore I needed to provide a `pnpmOverride`. Actually, I think you need to do that regardless whether you use a monorepo or not.

### For rush monorepos

- you need to use at least version `5.79.0`. Before that version, it was not possible to define `pnpmOverrides`. See https://rushjs.io/pages/configs/pnpm-config_json/
- provide the following value to `globalOverrides` within `pnpm-config.json`:

```json
"globalOverrides": {
    "@react-pdf/font": "2.2.1",
    "@react-pdf/pdfkit": "2.1.0"
},
```

### For plain pnpm repos

- add the `pnpm.overrides` object to your `package.json`. See https://pnpm.io/package_json#pnpmoverrides

```json
// package.json

{
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
        "@react-pdf/font": "2.2.1",
        "@react-pdf/pdfkit": "2.1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i used "@react-pdf/renderer": "^1.6.8", this version. and working fine

Comment: Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from @react-pdf/renderer@1.6.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer
npm ERR!   @react-pdf/renderer@"1.6.12" from the root project

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
  "overrides": {
    "@react-pdf/font": "2.2.0",
    "@react-pdf/pdfkit": "2.1.0",
  }
```